# Blur/reduce contrast of images in browsers

Tags: firefox, images, internet-explorer, browser-addons

As my nature of profession, I imposed to work for a 'sexy' like web site. I would like to know is there any tool available for Internet Explorer and Mozilla, which partially shows the images. 
I could not use 'Load Images automatically' option because I want to show it, but I want to blur/reduce contrast of the images. 
Anybody know of any plug-ins available for browsers esp. IE and Mozilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building upon AmpedWeb's answer, you can find (or create) the userContent.css for Mozilla-based browsers (e.g. `~/.mozilla/seamonkey/somerandomstring/chrome/userContent.css`), put the following in there, and restart your browser:

```
@-moz-document domain(some.domain.example.com) {
    img { opacity: 0.4 !important; }

    /* or, if you know of a CSS class name that marks the images */
    .classnamehere { opacity: ... }
}
```

It will make your images 60% transparent on that domain.

Note that this only works for `<img>` tags; if the images are embedded in any other way, they will appear normal.

Comment: Wow I need this how can i do it. Please explain :) Where should I put the CSS file in Windows. Can I apply it only for a single website ?

Comment: On Windows, it is something like `C:/Documents and Settings/user/Application Data/Mozilla/SeaMonkey/Profiles/somerandomstring`. Search for userContent-example.css to find the correct directory.

Comment: :( I could NOT find the folder specified. I am using Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: Type this into your file manager's address bar: `%AppData%`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find you something but couldn't.

The only thing I can think of would be to create a stylesheet that sets the alpha of images to be really high.

I have no idea how you could auto-load that stylesheet on all of your webpages, but I know it can be done.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mraufk/QjmmN/